# Find the replacement for `?`

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

```
624  -->   20
532  -->  117
634  -->  152
723  -->   40
443  -->  175
825  -->   ?
```

What should be filled in the last place so as to maintain the logical pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> **$39$**
>
>  because the digits are used as follows:
>  $6^2 - 4^2 = 20$
>  $5^3 - 2^3 = 117$
>  $6^3 - 4^3 = 152$
>  $7^2 - 3^2 = 40$
>  $4^4 - 3^4 = 175$
>  $8^2 - 5^2 = 39$